# How to associate a directory with my application

Tags: c++, delphi, registry

I don't want to associate extension but Folder. So that when I click on Desktop to tell OS to use my application, and not Explorer.

I've tried to substitute in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command explorer.exe with my program but it's not working properly cause then I open with my application also Control Panel and other stuff, which is not what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm only guessing, but I think the answer might be "don't do that"

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do can be achieved by implementing a custom **IShellFolder**.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144093(v=vs.85).aspx has the details . At a minimum you have to implement

1. IPersistFolder Interface
2. IShellFolder Interface
3. IEnumIDList Interface

This is what for example the **Google Drive** uses

Comment: I've came on this solution but it's a quite complicate to implement cause I need to have DLL (COM) that will start my main exe, handle these calls etc.
I was hoping there is some simpler solution.

To dirrectly call my exe file.

Comment: @IvanMark This is the only way to the best of my knowledge

Comment: Remember that you will need 32 bit and 64 bit shell extensions so if you plan to use Delphi, XE2 is needed.

Comment: I don't have XE2, but XE, so I was thinking to make this part under some free compiler (Lazarus) or to produce it in C++.

If someone has some C examples it would be great for start.

Comment: FPC never used to be very good at producing COM servers. When I faced this problem a few years back and had to write a 64 bit shell extension, I did it in C++. Not bundles of fun, but not so bad all the same.

Answer (score 0):

`Folder` ProgID denotes any folders, including non-filesystem ones. Correct ProgID for your case is `Directory`.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#data_sources)